# add every product as a new item into cart instead of updating quantity

Tags: magento, cart

I am using following custom code to add product in cart for magento

```
$qty=2;
for($i=1;$i<=$qty;$i++){
 $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_REQUEST['productid']);
 $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
 $cart->init();
 $cart->addProduct($product,array('qty'=>'1','customvar'=>$_REQUEST['customval']));$cart->save();
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
}
```

I have called this code using ajax, This code adds a single quote in cart with quantity 2, I want to add two quotes with quantity one. How can I do this?

Comment: why you modify the code. you can use ajax cart instead of writing your own code

Comment: I needed results on new page where I needed my custom code so I added this code. Isn't this possible with above code?

Comment: try /get Product 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
//get Item
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);

$quote->getCart()->updateItem(array($item->getId()=>array('qty'=>$qty)));
$quote->getCart()->save();

Comment: what is the value of $quote? I have used Mage::getModel('sales/quote') and it gave error
"Call to a member function updateItem() on a non-object".

Comment: $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362702/magento-programatically-update-cart-via-event

Comment: Above link is for updating cart values after cart has been saved but I want to run my function when adding values in cart.

Comment: as per standard create you own extension in this condition. and check for cart save event and then write this code in your obwser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362702/magento-programatically-update-cart-via-event

Comment: this also not working

Comment: Does anyone got any solution for this? I am still stuck.

Comment: @user0509 did you get the solution or not, because i also want same

Answer (score 1):

It worked after extending function representProduct($product) in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/model/Quote/Item.php.
used return false.